# When I should split class into struct and struct builder class?

Tags: design-patterns

For example, we have next class.

```
class Request{
public:
  RequestHeader header;
  String body;

  Request(const RequestHeader& header, const String& body); 
  Request(const String& json); 
};
```

Some articles recommend split `Request` entity and `Request` build logic. For example, next.

```
struct Request{ //RequestDTO?
  RequestHeader header;
  String body;
};

class RequestBuilder{
public:
  static Request build(const RequestHeader& header, const String& body);
  static Request build(const String& json);
};
```

When we should use this recommendation?
At first sight, it is useless complex. Constructor are normal part of a class. Why we should avoid this?

Comment: Patterns are often described as `a solution to a problem in a context`. You use them when you have a specific problem, not just because it's a "good practice". What do those articles say? To which problem is this the solution? As for HTTP Requests, the *request itself* may be simple but its contents are anything but - you may need to retrieve JSON data through GET, POST or PATCH, use HTTPS or not, use specific headers, authenticate etc. It's impossible to do all that in a Request constructor. A Builder or Factory can create and fill Requests specific to each use case.

Answer (score 0):

The separation you showed looks odd, as the `RequestBuider` doesn't look like it adds anything and it might increase the cognitive load one needs to have.

As a heavy opinion based answer, I do like using [fluent builders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) or named arguments (in languages that support this) to make the code more readable. My rule of thumb is to use a constructor with up to 3 parameters; maybe use a fluent builder when I have a class that receives 4-7 arguments; and definitely use one when there are 7+ arguments.

It's important to keep in mind that code should be easy to read and the intent should be trivial to understand (as much as possible). This will help maintaining the code and make everyones life a lot better :).